# How to have one checkbox checked by default angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I have one checkbox checked by default when the page loads between two toggling check boxes. my code:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/456/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.changeAxis1 = function() {
        if ($scope.thirtyDay) {
                    $scope.wholeTimeline = false;

    }
                };

     $scope.changeAxis2 = function() {
            if($scope.wholeTimeline) {
                    $scope.thirtyDay = false;  

                }
    };
};
```

view

```
 <label class='checkboxes' id='checkbox_1'>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="thirtyDay" ng-change="changeAxis1()">
        Two
        </label>
         <label class='checkboxes' id='checkbox_2'>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="wholeTimeline" ng-change="changeAxis2()">
        One
        </label>
```

Comment: Set `model` = `true` for ex. `$scope.thirtyDay = true;`

Comment: yes I have already tried that it did not work

Comment: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/cjs2xd8h/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize one of the values to `true` in your controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.changeAxis1 = function() {
        if ($scope.thirtyDay) {
            $scope.wholeTimeline = false;
        }
    };

    $scope.changeAxis2 = function() {
         if($scope.wholeTimeline) {
            $scope.thirtyDay = false;  
         }
    };

    $scope.thirtyDay = true;
};
```

You also need to have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in your view in order for Angular to do anything:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/457/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-checked="expression"`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="expression" ng-model="thirtyDay" ng-change="changeAxis1()">
        Two
```

and put some logic for expression how you want the checkbox to be checked